# (change) event is not being called for my custom select

Tags: angular

I have created my custom select. Which is working fine except the **(change)** event.

I have shared the idea from [here](http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel).

I have used ControlValueAccesor.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/XOcNbk4h2LT1HqLYKG1R?p=preview) is my plunker code.

Here is the usage.

```html
 <form-select 
    [label]="'Title'"
    [name]="'nameCPDTitle'"
    [(ngModel)]="name"
    (change)="myFun()"
    >  
            <form-select-option 
                *ngFor="let title of titleList" 
                [ngValue]="title.value">{{title.value}}</form-select-option> 
</form-select>
```

Comment: Try adding a `change` output to your custom select. I'm not sure that using the built-in change on a custom component would work ...

Comment: try using `(ngModelChange)` if using `ngModel`

Comment: Look at this plunker it works with (change) https://plnkr.co/edit/MU0lnnMvO7h3IUjaSZ4q?p=preview

Comment: It works with `change` because there is used `input.change` event which is bubbling

Comment: Your control should work with `ngModelChange` https://plnkr.co/edit/vvceH3cIg2Bfz9B1lMY4?p=preview Select `Mrs`

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote `this.displayText = this.placeholder;` because `displayText` represents selected value

Comment: But first time if any value is not selected then placeHolder will be shown. Though the logic is not complete there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(ngModelChange)` if using `ngModel`

The ngModel data property sets the element's value property and the `ngModelChange` event property listens for changes to the element's value.

```
<form-select  [label]="'Title'" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="myFun()">  
</form-select>
```

Can see a [plnkr demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/P3q1PeDwOqHjMyRBRZ1Z?p=preview)

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh got it you are expecting to trigger a function if any things change in form correct

Comment: Yes, It is working. But why the change is not working? While it is warking in similar program. plnkr.co/edit/vvceH3cIg2Bfz9B1lMY4?p=preview

Comment: `ngModelChange` event property listens for changes to the element's value with `ngModel`

Comment: Actually change should also work here but its not working with ngModel in angular2 since beta 4 release.. It was working fine in alpha version

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh But now angular itself has documentation to use `ngModelChange` with `ngModel` can check here open the link angular.io/guide/template-syntax and search `Ctrl + f` for keywords ngModelChange.. Note dont use angular search input field use browser shortcut `Ctrl + f` to search